# What is the relationship between System.IdentityModel and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, token, identitymodel

I'm using old code for JWT validation, and the reference to `System.IdentityModel` throws an error unless I add the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` dependency.

I would like to know why this happens.

```cs
private string generateJwtToken(Employee employee)
{
    var tokenHandler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
    var symmetricKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
    var claimRe = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("re", employee.re.ToString());
    var claimRl = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("role", employee.role.ToString());
    var claims = new[] { claimRe, claimRl };

    var tokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(symmetricKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

Note: code from when I was studying.

Comment: You probably don't have the right NuGet dependencies to use System.IdentityModel, and  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient incidentally supplied them.

Comment: How can I add the dependency on System.IndentityModel? I can't find it in the NuGet package list

Comment: Look at the docs for the class (not just the namespace) you need, and it will list the Assembly and NuGet package that contains it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.signingcredentials?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest